# Problems with for(auto c: str) in avr-g++

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++14, microcontroller, avr-gcc

I'm learning how to program an avr microcontroller. As it is a microcontroller you can't use std:string, so instead you use const char str[] when you need a string.

If you want to transmit a string in C++ you can write something like this:

```
const char str[] = "my string";

for(auto c: str)
    transmit(c);
```

Thats very pretty, but it doesn't compile with avr-g++ because this compiler doesn't provide the functions 'begin' and 'end'.

No problem, because it's very easy to write them:

```
struct End_iterator_const_char_array{ };

bool operator==(const char* p, End_iterator_const_char_array)
{ return *p == '\0'; }

bool operator==(End_iterator_const_char_array e, const char* p)
{ return (p == e);}

bool operator!=(const char* p, End_iterator_const_char_array e)
{ return !(p == e);}

bool operator!=(End_iterator_const_char_array e, const char* p)
{ return !(e == p);}


const char* begin(const char arr[])  
{return &arr[0];}

End_iterator_const_char_array end(const char arr[])
{return End_iterator_const_char_array{};}
```

With these code, I can write the usual for loop:

```
for(auto p = begin(str); p != end(str); ++p)
     transmit(*p);
```

and it compiles and works perfectly. But if I try to use

```
for(auto c: str)
    transmit(c);
```

it doesn't compile. The compiler tells me

"error: 'begin' was not declare in this scope".

Why? What's the problem?

Compiler: avr-g++ 4.9.2
Flags: -std=C++14 -pedantic

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give the complete error, it might be to do with `char const *` vs `const char arr[]` but without the full error I can't be sure.

Comment: In order to work with a range-based for loop, `begin()` and `end()` need to return the same type prior to C++17.

Comment: @Carcigenicate libstdc++ is not available for avr.

Comment: try putting `begin` and `end` in `std` namespace.

Comment: @sajadbanooie that's undefined behaviour

Comment: Aren't there begin and end in <iterator>  for arrays, if rage based for is provided?

Comment: Works for me with avr-g++ 4.9.2 without your operators and without 
 your begin/end. The compiler must be supplying implementations. Disassembly looks fine as well.